# C# auto update chart when textbox is changed

Tags: c#, r, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a windows form consisting of a series of textboxes and a button. 
The user needs to input some data into the textboxes and then the code uses these inputs to do some calculation. 
The user then clicks the button and a chart is generated showing the results of the calculations. 
The chart is done using R which is connected to C# via R.Net.

The question is: how can I make the chart to update dynamically as soon as the user changes some input in one of the textboxes (so without first clicking the button that generates the graph)?

I thought that I would need some loop that constantly checks if any of the textboxes has been changed but I cannot make this work:

```
foreach (Control subctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (subctrl is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)subctrl).TextChanged += new EventHandler();
        }

    }
```

TextChanged should trigger the buttonClick event so that the reated code that generates the graph is executed.
What is a good approach for this problem? Thanks.

<<<< EDIT >>>>>

Here is my code for the form:

```
public partial class myInputForm : Form
{
    public myInputForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       // call methods to run calculations using new inputs from textboxes
       plotGraph(); // plot the new results
    }

}
```

I would like to keep the calculation methods and the plot function *plotGraph()* inside the button1_Click event.

Trying to adopt Refus L's suggestion, I am adding the following to the partial class myInputForm above:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (IsValidText(textBox.Text)) 
    {
         textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    }
    else
    {
    DisplayBadTextWarning(textBox.Text);
    }
}


private void myInputForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        var textBox = control as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }
 }
```

But this still doesn't work. If I insert the following:

```
this.myFirstBox.textChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

directly in the code that is automatically generated by the form designer it works and a change in the textbox myFirstBox triggers the button click and thus the plot. 
But I would need to write a line for each textbox cause the foreach doesn't work there. 
Can you please explain how to set this up to work in my form? Thanks.

Comment: You are hooking up the event handler again inside the event handler. Don't do that. Just call button1_Click().

Comment: It seems that is the **private void myInputForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}** part that is not working. I put a breakpoint in it but when I change text in one of the textboxes nothing happens and this event is not triggered. Is it wrong how it is written? Should I use "myInputForm_Load" since my form is called "myInputForm"? You used "Form1_Load" in your example... thanks for your help.

Comment: .PS. what is the right place to put these lines of code? Is it possible that I'm simply putting the code in the wrong location?

Comment: Yes, you should put it in the load event of your form. You should try it and see what happens. If you don't experiment on your own, you're not going to learn!

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify an existing method that you want to handle the event. Ideally you'd have a separate method that updates the chart, which can be called from anywhere. Then you can call it from your TextChanged or Button_Click event, but these two control events are not tied together (in TextChanged you may want to do some validation on the text first). Also, if you want to update the chart from some other place, you have an independent method you can call that will do it.

For example, if you have this method to update the chart:

```
private void UpdateChart()
{
    // Do something here to update the chart
}
```

You can call it from your event handlers:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateChart();
}

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You might have some data validation on the TextBox.Text here, 
    // which you wouldn't need in the Button_Click event
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (IsValidText(textBox.Text)) 
    {
        // Now update the chart
        UpdateChart();
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayBadTextWarning(textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Then you can hook up all your `TextBox.TextChanged` events to the custom handler above:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Dynamically hook up all the TextBox TextChanged events to your custom method
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        var textBox = control as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So since the graph is generated with a button click, can I write textBox.TextChanged += button1_Click ?

Comment: Sure, since it has the same method signature it will work. Try it and see!

Comment: Probably a better design would be to create an `UpdateChart()` method, and then call that from `Button1_Click`. Likewise, you should create a `TextBox_TextChanged` method that also calls the `UpdateChart` method, and hook your textbox textchanged events to that. This separates the code in a good way. If you ever want to change what happens when the button is clicked, you don't have to worry that it will also always happened when text changes. Or if you want to update the chart from some other place, you don't have to call Button_Click to do it.

Comment: Hi Rufus, I have edit my post because I have tried your code. Can yu please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @opt The code you posted is trying to add the event handler to the TextBox.TextChanged event *again* **inside the event handler!**. Just call the button1_Click() method instead: `if (IsValidText(textBox.Text)) { button1_Click(sender, e); }`